# How to configure apache/php for up to 2 gig file upload

Tags: apache-2.2, php, upload

I am trying to upload the largest file I can through apache using php and a flash upload program.

What variables do I need to adjust in my Apache configs or in my php configs to allow such a large upload size?

Comment: I'm curious if this will just be local network based usage? Or are you going for real world internet uploads?

Answer (score 2):

In your php.ini file, you need to change the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size fields.  It should look like this:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
```

and

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 2048M
```

Depending on your already existing settings you might need to also make changes in php.ini to the Resource Limits section, such as max_execution_time, max_input_time, and memory_limit.

Then restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

On Debian GNU/Linux, we have the file:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

in which we need to adjust the values for the following settings:

```
memory_limit
max_post_size
upload_max_filesize
```

And needless to say, memory_limit should be higher that those who follow, and max_post_size should be higher than upload_max_filesize.  You as the administrator will need to determine those necessary sizes.